# Защита api в laravel, передача изображений

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

Как защитить api в laravel 5.6, чтобы оно было доступно, например, только из android приложения или, например, только из браузера? И как передавать изображения  через api?

Comment: если нужна надежная авторизация то можно через jwt, но желательно делать не большой срок жизни и делать refresh перед истечением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Защитить никак. можно какие-то костыли сделать но 100% гарантии все равно не будет. Правильно делать токены - которые уникально идентифицируют внешний ресурс и с него крутить. Вашим API должно быть не особо важно с браузера пришел запрос или с андроида.

2) Изображения передают обычно ссылкой (а внешний ресурс сам его подгружает).

Comment: Можете привести пример или дать ссылку на такие костыли?

Comment: @ArturHan Все зависит от того как вы работаете с API, конкретных статей не может быть, везде свое. Например сделать доступ только из браузера - это можно сделать путем проверки UserAgent и прочее такое.

Comment: А как идентифицировать android приложение?

Comment: @ArturHan ну тоже можно кучу всего придумать. Вы-же разрабатываете это приложение - путсь он какой-то флаг посылает. А вообще яж не просто так написал про токены. Т.е. ваше API будет отвечать при наличии токена, а токены можно выдавать отдельно для андроидов и отдельно для десктопа. Тут у вас суть вопроса в другом: как отличить два неизвестных устройства по каким-то признакам ( тут априори не будет 100% способа ).